# Start animation when scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have progress bars on my website to visually display percentages, which have an animation to make them scroll along with the page. However this animation starts as soon as the page is loaded.

My issue is the progress bars are lower down the page, and when the page is loaded you cannot see the animation in time. Is there any way to start the animation only when the element is in view?

```css
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  10% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.bara1 {
  border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #7ac1cf;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -32px;
  z-index: 2;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.barb1 {
  border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.textbox {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bara1" style="width: 92%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">92%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 78%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">78%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 56%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">56%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 40%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">40%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 31%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">31%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>
```

Comment: Try with `scrollTop` with javascript/jQuery. when the element is visible, you can add or remove css property or class to the element. 

you can refer this: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-style-of-elements-on-scroll-using-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Basically a class is added only when the bar starts to be visible (in the exemple below I've named this class `animate`).
I've added in your HTML code a placeholder to simule the content before the bars and move `animation-name: example` from `.bara1` to `.bara1.animate`

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersections => {
  intersections.forEach(({
    target,
    isIntersecting
  }) => {
    target.classList.toggle('animate', isIntersecting);
  });
}, {
  threshold: 0
});

document.querySelectorAll('.bara1').forEach(div => {
  observer.observe(div);
});
```

```css
#placeholder {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  10% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.bara1 {
  border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #7ac1cf;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -32px;
  z-index: 2;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.bara1.animate {
  animation-name: example;
}

.barb1 {
  border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.textbox {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
```

```html
<section id="placeholder">This is a placeholder</section>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 92%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">92%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 78%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">78%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 56%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">56%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 40%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">40%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>

<div class="bara1" style="width: 31%">
  <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">31%</font>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="barb1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by adding a class to the surrounding container when it is scrolled into view and define the animation only for that class (respectively its children). You would call that check in an event handler for the `scroll` event.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(container)) {
    container.classList.add('inView');
  }
});
```

```css
.inView .bara1 {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
```

For that it is necessary to define a function that checks if the element is visible:

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var elemTop = rect.top;
  var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

  var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
  
  return isVisible;
}
```

Furthermore it is important to omit the inline styles (`width`) for all `.bara1` and instead set them with JavaScript, for example by using the text from the `font` elements. Otherwise there will be a flickering, caused by the full (inline-) width that gets resetted by the animation.

```js
const bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bara1');
    
for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
  const percent = bars[i].querySelector('font').textContent;
  bars[i].style.width = percent;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
let container = document.querySelector('#container');

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var elemTop = rect.top;
  var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

  var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
  
  return isVisible;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(container)) {
    container.classList.add('inView');

    const bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bara1');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
      const percent = bars[i].querySelector('font').textContent;
      bars[i].style.width = percent;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#placeholder {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  10% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.bara1 {
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #7ac1cf;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -32px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.inView .bara1 {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.barb1 {
  border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.textbox {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder">placeholder</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="bara1">
    <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">92%</font>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barb1"></div>

  <div class="bara1">
    <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">78%</font>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barb1"></div>

  <div class="bara1">
    <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">56%</font>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barb1"></div>

  <div class="bara1">
    <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">40%</font>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barb1"></div>

  <div class="bara1">
    <div class="textbox"><b>text</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <font size="2px" color="#def7fc">31%</font>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barb1"></div>
</div>
```